# What to put as discoverable services when using Eureka?

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am following a course about microservice architecture using spring, covering netflix's eureka.

[image: Project structure]

The clientui serves webpages and calls the 3 microservices when needed.
The config-server serves configuration for the 3 microservices from a git repo.

Of course the 3 microservices are registered as eureka clients.

**My questions are** :

- should the config server and also be registered as an eureka client, or is there no benefit in doing so?
- what about the clientui (which is the web entry point) ? can it be registered as an eureka client in order to benefit from load balancing system and if yes, how then should the app be accessed by clients?

Answer (score 1):

About your first question :- Yes you can register config server as eureka client. Benefit of this will be that in terms of service management it will give you a single point of visibility of all the services. Also later if you try to expand your app in terms of distributed architecture and say you implement an api gateway like zuul, it will be easy for you to setup a fallback config server say if one config server goes down requests can be routed to other config server and so on.

---

About your second question :- Honestly speaking , I didn't understand it very well in first place. I have never seen any ui service registering to eureka so I am not very sure about this. Still if you have more doubts about it , you can let me know like is it a angular ui or is it a http based client or what.